# Using PIVOT over a group by query

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I've been trying to create a pivot for following query :

```
select mainstate, customertypeid, count(1) as [counter] from customers group by customertypeid, mainstate
```

This query should display as many customers types per state, it looks like this (order by doesn't matter) :

```
State|customertypeid|counter
  UT      3            200
  CA      3            500
  NY      3            300  
  UT      2            100
  CA      2            200
  NY      2            120
  UT      1             20
  CA      1             50
  NY      1             30
```

I've tried to use PIVOT as follow (I'm sure I'm wrong) :

```
SELECT *
FROM ( select mainstate, customertypeid, count(1) as [counter] from customers where customertypeid in (1,2,3) and mainstate != '' group by customertypeid, mainstate) as NonPivotedDataForReport2
PIVOT
(
COUNT([counter])
FOR mainstate IN ([# of Amb],[# Whole Sale Customers],[# Retail Customers])
) AS PivotedDataForReport2
```

I'm getting this :

```
customertypeid|type1|type2|type3
       1         0     0     0
       2         0     0     0
       3         0     0     0
```

and the report should look like this :

```
State|type1|type2|type3
UT     20    100   200
CA     50    200   500
NY     30    120   300
```

*Ps : I don't really want to go back to CASE + SUM Statement,

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do:

```
SELECT  mainstate [State],
        [1] type1,
        [2] type2,
        [3] type3
FROM (  SELECT mainstate, customertypeid, COUNT(1) [counter] 
        FROM customers 
        WHERE customertypeid in (1,2,3) 
        AND mainstate != '' 
        GROUP BY customertypeid, mainstate) as NonPivotedDataForReport2
PIVOT(SUM([counter]) FOR customertypeid IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS PivotedDataReport2
```

Answer (score 1):

This (perhaps slightly edited) should do the job for you without case/sum/pivot. Create a temp table, insert starting data and then dynamically add columns depending on how many customer type ids there is.

```
declare @s varchar(10), @xx1 varchar(500)

select distinct state into #temp from customers

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT distinct customertypeid from customers
open MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor into @S
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        set @xx1 = 'alter table #temp add ['+@s+'] varchar(5)'
        execute sp_executesql @xx1
            set @xx1 = 'update a set a.['+@s+'] = coalesce(b.counter,0) from #temp a, customers b where b.customertypeid = '+@s+' and a.state = b.state'
            execute sp_executesql @xx1
        FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor into @S
    End
Close myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor

select * from #temp
```

Comment: Lamak's answer is the simpler way if you know the columns ahead and the customer ID's don't change. If you don't know the columns before hand and it's on the fly, dynamically adding the columns will be the way.